# How can I make the program stop if the input is invalid?

Tags: python, break

I need to know how can I make my program continue with the login ONLY if the entered username is valid, but if an incorrect username is entered it should stop, but the break function just doesn't work.
I am a beginner, and I am truly sorry about posting about something this simple, but I cant get it to work and I cant find a direct answer elsewhere.[image]

Code:

```py
if a == x:
    print('entered username is valid')
else:
    print('entered username is invalid')
    break
```

I tried using {}, and it didn't quite work; it said something about just not working properly but the brackets don't work in any scenario.

Comment: `break` is used to terminate loops but you don't have any loop in your code. If you want to not continue executing code put it inside a function and change the break for a return. You can also put the code you want to execute inside the if condition.

Comment: I suggest you rethink your learning strategy and work through some tutorials start to end.

Comment: The title should describe your _specific_ question, in a way that distinguishes it from other questions on this site (including ones that are "basic").

Comment: Also, [code should be posted as text, not as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122). In addition to the [meta] link earlier in this comment, see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: If you accept a tip, start naming your variables with descriptive names. The sooner you change `if a == x` for something like `if inputName == userName` the better. The future you will be very happy if you do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while a!="":
  if a!=x:
    print("username invalid")
    break
  else:
    print("username login valid")
    b=str(input("enter password"))
    if b==y:
      print("logged in successfully")
      break
```

you can work with something similar, break are only for loops , you should integrate it with while/for loop, for this example we entered in a loop that loos on while your "a" username input is not empty

Comment: hey,
this helped me a bit, but i found out that even if the password is correct it loops back to username login valid and after that enter password again, and you can do this indefinetely.
can i somehow make it end it right there if the login was successful?

Comment: add break right after the logge din succesfully i added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

`break` is for loops. If you want your program to stop, try replacing `break` by `sys.exit()`.

Of course, you'll need to add at the beginning of your program:

```py
import sys
```

because `sys.exit()` is a function of module `sys`.